# '&' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:Name'

Tags: c++, xml

whenever i am giving any special character to a variable, it throws below error.
element Type: Schemas validity error : Element Type': '&' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:Name'.

It accepts only colon (:).

Below is my schema.

```
  <element name="measCollecFile">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
       <choice>
        <element name="Types">
            <simpleType>
                <list itemType="Name"/>
                   </simpleType>
                      </element>
                      <element name="Type"
                               minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <complexType>
                          <simpleContent>
                            <extension base="Name">
                              <attribute name="p"
                                         type="positiveInteger" use="required"/>
                            </extension>
                          </simpleContent>
                        </complexType>
        </element>
        </choice>
    </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Can anyone help me for finding from where this error is coming and how to get rid of it..

Comment: In   code also i checked , nowhere its mentioned about restriction of special characters

Comment: An ampersand can't stand by itself in XML. That said, provide a minimal but complete example, refer to the posting guidelines.

Comment: Its not only ampersand ...for every special characters and numbers , its showing same error ...What is posting guidelines??

Comment: Have you tried `&amp;` ?

Comment: I had written one function for changing the special characters (&,<,>,',") to respective xml escape form. so if i am giving any of these characters to the attribute value , then the function is successfully converting it to respective escaped form that i had checked manually. To check this functionality i had written one testcase where i am passing these characters and expecting the converted format. But for this attribute i got the schema error as mentioned in the question,because of failure during model validation. I am guessing its because of the "<extension base="Name">".

Answer (score 1):

You have some invalid XML, which you haven't shown us. It's invalid because your schema requires some element to have a value that is a valid instance of xs:Name, and a valid instance of xs:Name cannot contain an ampersand.

Comment: But i have only this part of xml for the respective attribute;

Can you please let me know what are the other characters , which are invalid for xs:Name

Comment: @Pragyan, surely you can find some XSD reference which tells you what the rules for a valid xs:Name are. It's not my job to search the documentation for you.